# Flexbox text alignment on mobile

Tags: text, mobile, flexbox, icons, alignment

So, I am using flexbox for some columns. Basically column 1 is left-aligned, column two i centered, and column three is right-aligned. No big deal, or so I thought. In Chrome, everything looks fine, even when looking at things through Chrome's Inspect tool...but on my iPhone I can't get the right column to `justify-content`.

My code looks like:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div>
            <p><i class="far fa-dot-circle"></i> <a href="">Watch</a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><a href=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p><i class="fas fa-donate"></i> <a href="">Give</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css looks like:

```
#nav div {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(1) {
    background: #00ff00;
    justify-content: left;
}

#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
    justify-content: center;
}

#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(3) {
    background: #0000ff;
    justify-content: right;
}

#nav img {
    max-width: 175px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav i {
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kw5g3h7/

I added the following code this morning and this works:

```
#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(3) p {
text-align: right;
width: 100%;
```

}

I don't like this approach, it seems like to me the `justify-content` just isn't working is there a way to fix this using flexbox? I'm trying to understand why my original code isn't working on my iPhone? Maybe it's because I have Font Awesome icons in front of the text, I just don't know. Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Josh

Comment: I just confirmed it, if I remove `#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(1)` and `#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(3)`, but leave `#nav > .wrap > div:nth-child(3) p` everything still works on both desktop and mobile...but that means it's now working without the `justify-content` does that just not work on mobile?

Comment: Please share an image of the output that you're expecting on mobile. Also, `#nav div` doesn't seem right. This means that all the children of `.wrap` are also flexboxes which you probably don't want? You can make only `.wrap` div as flex, and align the content inside its flex-items using `text-align`.

Comment: It’s actually on my test site right now: http://joshrodg.com/splash, this is the one I added the extra code to this morning :-)

Comment: @veesar yep, that's right, each div is flexed because I'm using align-items to make the content of each column or each div in my wrap vertically align in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize until now that I hadn't ever posted my final code. This is what I ended up with: https://jsfiddle.net/tc36e24s/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="head">
     <div id="nav">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()" class="close"><i class="ion-android-close"></i></a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="">Watch</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Give</a></li>
             <li><a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" /></a></li>
             <li><a href="">Visitors</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
        
    <div id="logo">
        <p><a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo" /></a></p>
            
        <div onclick="openNav()" class="open">
            <i class="ion-android-menu"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #009151;
}

#head {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

#nav ul {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#nav ul img {
    max-width: 175px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav ul i {
    color: #9ac2e7;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#nav li {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#logo {
    display: flex;
}

#logo img {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #head .open {
        color: #9ac2e7;
        font-size: 30px;
        margin: 20px 30px;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #head .open:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #nav {
        background: #9ac2e7;
        display: none;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #nav ul {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nav ul a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #nav li {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
    #nav li:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav .close {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 30px;
        top: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #nav .close {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav[style] {
        display: block !important;
    }
    #nav ul {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
    }
    #nav ul a {
        color: #9ac2e7;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #nav li {
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    #logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JS

```
function openNav() {
    document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.body.style.overflow="scroll";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.display = "none";
}
```

I added some JS to make my menu work on mobile, but other than that this is code I went with...which is pretty much the same as before except I added two additional links (one on each side of the logo).

Thanks,
Josh